# Send Email as html

Tags: html, css

Im doing an email form , design already done and look nice in web browsers , problem is ,when i send it through email , receiving email does not look the same as if i open it in browsers
here is image from browser and also from email ![enter image description here][1] ![enter image description here][2]

here is page you can visit it [Emial page][3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML emails are still having to be built primarily using tables due to the numerous email clients and their varying issues with other HTML elements like div tags.

See this for more info: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3472/div-tags-in-html-email-newsletters/